# Multiple http requests every timeout

Tags: html, angular, http, request

I have developed an web app using angular which connects with spotify and enables customers in my bar to add songs to the current playlist.

To do so I am calling the spotify API to get the current track, where i start a timeout using the time left of the currently playing song. Once this ends, I call the method again, as well as calling a request to get the playlist.

Currently using this method, it will  make a few requests every few minutes.

To make it more accurate and update more readily, I want to make this timeout every ten seconds.Is this bad practice, and will it slow the app down or is this recommended?

Answer (score 0):

if it is requesting more than one every time probably you need to make a little research about bubbling.

Shortly; probably your method is connected to a button and when the user clicked it, button calls the method. And also somewhere in your code you calling that method again *(probably in a parent form element)*. when you click on a button that is inside a form, you also click to that form too so it calls both methods of form and button. In your case both of the same function so your method runs two times.